# CRM 4.0 workflow activity error message feedback to user

Tags: workflow-foundation, dynamics-crm

Is it possible to override the default error message in CRM 4.0 that occurs if a workflow fails? Is it recommended against doing so? This seems like the best spot for a remote, non-technical user to read a simple error message that any custom workflow activity has thrown. I would imagine the code extension point for this is overriding the HandleFault method of the Activity base class.

```
protected override ActivityExecutionStatus HandleFault(ActivityExecutionContext executionContext, Exception exception)
{            
    return base.HandleFault(executionContext, exception);
}
```

Here is the default (aka the "always-there-but-no-one-reads-it" text):
[image]

Comment: I'm going to guess its not customizable, but give it a shot and let us know.  You can usually get a more detailed exception message in the ErrorMessage field of the asyncoperation table.

Comment: The entity itself is not customizable. However, there is a way around that, see http://nishantrana.wordpress.com/2010/05/04/getting-the-error-messages-for-custom-workflow-activity/. The data I am after can be found in the message column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible, yet not supported, to change the form of asyncoperation to show the message field, see link below. A supported way is to do an advanced search and include this column. I will take the latter approach for now.

http://nishantrana.wordpress.com/2010/05/04/getting-the-error-messages-for-custom-workflow-activity/